# Farthest distance of a polygon point from it's centroid

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I've tackled this problem from two angles now but am definitely missing knowledge of the PostGIS library to actually execute my needs.

Basically I have a single Polygon (no multipolygons) contained in a column called "geom". They are all pretty simple shapes for city boundaries. I've determined how to calculate the centroid but I want to query what the longest point in the polygon is from the centroid.

More directly: I'm having trouble finding out how to break out the points from my geometry column, run `ST_Distance()` between the vertices and the centroid and output the longest distance.

I suspect I have to use `ST_DumpPoints()` but I don't grasp how to write the expression to do the rest.

My solutions have looked similar to this:

```
SELECT max(ST_Distance(ST_DumpPoints(geom), ST_Centroid(geom))) AS distance
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ST_DumpPoints()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) function returns a set of (geom, path) rows, where `geom` are the points from the polygon and `path` is an array of integer with (in this case) the ring of the polygon at position 1 and the index of the POINT within the ring at position 2. Since `ST_DumpPoints()` is a set-returning function, it should be used in a `FROM` clause. (While the examples are all functional, the PostGIS documentation uses the function in the `SELECT` clause, but that is bad practice and not recommended.)

In order to make it all work you need to make a [`LATERAL JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM): in the joined "table" `dump` you use a column from a previously specified table, `my_table t`. When done with a function, as in this case, the `LATERAL JOIN` is implicitly allowed.

```
SELECT t.id AS city_id,
       ST_Centroid(t.geom) AS center,
       max(ST_Distance(dump.geom, ST_Centroid(t.geom))) AS distance,
       dump.path AS path_to_the_burbs
FROM my_table t
JOIN ST_DumpPoints(t.geom) dump ON true
GROUP BY 1, 2, 4
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! I'll give you a bit more detail because your solution only half explains where I need to go with this. My geom values is actually an enclosed Polygon -- typically with 10-15 vertices in various shapes. The issue is I want to calculate the distance from the centroid to EACH of the polygon to determine the longest point. I could do this using a Minimum Bounding Circle but that seems needlessly complex.

Comment: I'm working on a different solution that may perhaps be more optimal:

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_CENTROID(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(geom)::geometry)),
ST_AsText(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(geom)::geometry)
FROM "Regions"

I'm thinking if I find the MBC and it's centroid I can calculate the distance from any of the polygons returned in the MBC.

Now I need to figure out how to calculate the radius from the centroid or the diameter. This is a round-about way to accomplish what I want but may work.

Comment: I don't understand these comments at all.  How does Patrick's answer not solve your problem?  What is an "enclosed" polygon as opposed to any polygon?  As points don't have length, what is a "longest" point?  Is this an X-Y situation where you haven't described your actual problem and instead have asked about what you think is the solution?

Comment: There's no need to be rude, jack. Patrick's solution didn't quite answer the question the way I was hoping so I moved onto a different solution.

As for your comment about no such thing as a "longest point", when I wrote the question I thought it was clear that I meant distance from the centroid to each vertex. No sarcasm needed. Seeing as he mostly answers the question, I'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: @ddibiase The way I read your original question, I think I pretty much answered it, so you did the right thing in accepting it. If you have additional questions, perhaps coming from seeing this answer, you should edit the question and leave a comment here. Reading code in a comment is quite difficult and other SO users struggling with a similar issue will see your question and my answer, but likely not these comments. In this case - you posted a question to get an idea of a solution direction, or so it seems - you might even be better off posing a new question with more complexity. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help Patrick. I realize I wasn't clear in the original question and certainly felt I needed to do what was right. There's no need for users to be nasty on great resources such as this. I ended up finding a solution to my problem.